# Ошибка связанная с итератором в векторах

Tags: c++, visual-c++

По заданию нужно написать класс mset который выполняет основной функционал класса set, но через класс vector. При этом нужно чтобы класс mset(тот что нужно написать) был шаблонным, не завязанным на конкретный тип данных. Я объявил итератор и в конструкторе я пытаюсь его обнулить началом вектора. На этой строке выдаётся вот такая вот ошибка:

*Ошибка    3   error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию*

*Ошибка 5   error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "vj"*

**Вопрос: В чём может быть дело?**

**Вопрос№2: Как это поправить?**

**Вопрос№3: Какова механика данной ошибки?**

код main'а не скидываю, так как там всего лишь вызов конструктора по умолчанию, вызов метода на добавление элемента и вызов печати множества.

код:

```
            #pragma once
            #include <vector>
            #include <iostream>
            #include <iomanip>
            using namespace std;
            template <typename tname>
            class mset
            {
            public:

                vector<tname> vecSet;
                vector<tname>::iterator vi;
                vector<tname>::iterator vj;
                mset()
                {
                    vecSet.reserve(1);
                    vecSet[0] = 0;
                    vi = vecSet.begin();
                    vj = vecSet.begin();
                }

                void Add(tname value)//добавление элемента в вектор
                {
                    vecSet.push_back(value);
                    sort();
                }
                void Rm(int index)//уничтожение элемента
                {
                        vi = index;
                        vecSet.erase(vi);
                        sort();
                }
                bool RmDb() // уничтожение дубликатов
                {
                    sort();
                    for (vi = vecSet.begin(); vi != vecSet.size(); vi + 1)
                    {
                        if (vecSet[vi] == vecSet[vi + 1])
                        {
                            vecSet.erase(vi);
                        }
                    }

                }
                tname TakeValue(int i)//взятие значения по индексу
                {
                    vi = vecSet.begin();
                    return vecSet[vi+i];
                }
                void sort()//сортировка
                {
                    for (vi = vecSet.begin(); vi != vecSet.size(); vi + 1)
                    {
                        for (vj = vecSet.begin(); vj != vecSet.size() - 1; j + 1)
                        {
                            if (vecSet[vj + 1] < vecSet[vj]) swap(vecSet[vj + 1], vecSet[vj]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                void Print()
                {
                    for (vi = vecSet.begin(); vi != vecSet.size(); vi+1)
                    {
                        cout << setw(1) << vecSet[vi];
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }
                ~mset()
                {
                }
            private:
            //  vector<tname>::iterator vecIt = 0;
            };
```

Comment: Тип итератора должен соответствовать типу вектора. А у вас вектор с шаблонным параметром, а итераторы почему-то `vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: да, не заметил. Сейчас поправлю вопрос. С изменением типов, возникают немного другого рода ошибки.

Comment: Описанные ошибки возникают 2 раза, для строки с обнулением vi и vj

Comment: Это потому что в конструкции `vector<tname>::iterator` `iterator` является зависимым (от параметра шаблона) именем и по-умолчанию воспринимается как название поля. Чтобы `iterator` воспринимался как название типа следует записать так  `typename vector<tname>::iterator`

Comment: подправил. Теперь ругается на операцию != используемую в цикле(метод print). Доступ к элементу я делаю через разыменование итератора.

Comment: Так а не надо сравнивать итератор с размером... Вообще прежде чем спрашивать, следует попытаться устранить ошибку самостоятельно, а то вы далеко не уедите.

Comment: вообше  не нужно хранить итераторы в классе, и  vi + 1 в цикле бессмысленная операция, возвращающий временный обьект,  j + 1   представляет сразу две ошибки, сравнивать итератор с размером вектора тоже ошибка,  и так везде у вас ошибки  разного рода. Также допущены    vi = vecSet.begin();
                    return vecSet[vi+i];  Итератор используете как индекс

Comment: я уже это исправил.

Comment: Теперь вопрос такой: а как правильно определить специализацию для одного метода в шаблонном классе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотя это и не ответ на вопрос, но всё же напишу:

То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, называется `flat_set`. В качестве примера можно взять `boost::flat_set`. Если вы хотите получить что-то похожее по функционалу на `std::set` - логично взять его интерфейс и не выумывать велосипед совсем с нуля. Интерфейс можно посмотреть [тут](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). В качестве типа итератора можно оставить `typename std::vector<T>::iterator` и `typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator` - в данном случае действительно нет смысла создавать свой итератор, итератор отсортированного вектора вполне соответствует требованиям итератора `std::set`

Фактически `flat_set` - это просто отсортированный вектор. Но это не значит, что каждый раз при вставке его нужно сортировать! Достаточно найти место, куда можно вставить элемент, для этого в стандартной библиотеке есть алгоритмы `lower_bound` и `upper_bound`. Не хотите использовать стандартные - реализуйте свой вариант, сути это не меняет. Т.е. вам нужно просто найти место вставки при помощи `upper_bound` и вставить элемент при помощи перегрузки `std::vector::insert(iterator_type it, value_type v)`

И зачем вам специализация для метода? Там же шаблонные методы если и есть, то сводятся к вызову аналогичных методов `std::vector`. Если нужна перегрузка внешней функции - пишите что-то вроде

```
template<class T> bool operator = (const mset<T>& lha, const mset<T>& rha) noexcept{
  return ...;
}
```

Comment: У меня по заданию требование реализовать именно set разработав свой класс и в нём элементы set'a хранить в векторе. 
А перегрузка метода Print не нужна, ибо я невнимательный косяк и просто забыл подключить <string>

Comment: Ответ принят просто чтоб был. Основные ответы были в комментариях. Всем спасибо за отклик